# Excel formula cells to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

How to convert excel to dataframe, where my excel contain formula for most of the fileds?

Tried Openpyxl, Pandas Excel, all retuning None for the formula filled fields. And I don't want to write the formula in python for those formula excel field, since there are n numbers of columns and the formula are quite complex. I just need the calculated values while reading the excel in python.

Comment: Then you don't want to use pandas, this is not how it works, it doesn't handle formulas. Either read the values (not formulas), or use a different tool.